# this user account does not have a password configured - bitbucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket, fatal-error

I want to create a project and push it to bitbucket repo.

I followed to instructions:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://nazar@bitbucket.org/nazar/blog.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

But I caught the next message:

```
nazar@desktop:~/Documents/rails/blog⟫ git push -u origin --all
remote: abort: this user account (nazar) does not have a password configured - to use your account over HTTPS, it is necessary to have a password set.
fatal: unable to access 'https://nazar@bitbucket.org/nazar/blog.git/': The requested URL returned error: 412
```

I used Github. And it had some `ssh` key generation option.

***Does exist something similar at Bitbucket?***

**SOLUTION:**

Able to use the same `ssh` key, generated for Github - [Generating SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys). All works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And it had some ssh key generation option.

Maybe so, but you didn't use an ssh URL for your repo

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:nazar/blog.git
```

If you use an https URL, your ssh public/private key would be ignored entirely.

Comment: I misunderstood... how to solve this trouble, any suggestions?

Comment: @nazar_art you can either associate a password to your bitbucket account (as in https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/245137/bitbucket-failing-for-lack-of-password-but-not-requesting-it), or generate new ssh public/private keys (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Add+an+SSH+key+to+an+account)